# C++ on Arduino - General Questions

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

1. If I call a function do I need to delete all variables used in it at the end or is that done automatically.
2. How to compare a String to "" and which object can I use instead of a string with is as easy as a string but not so big?
3. Is it possible to run C Python on Arduino or would this be just a waste of already limited resources?

Comment: Adafruit has micropython on some of their boards... https://www.adafruit.com/micropython

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you don't use `new` you don't need to `delete`
2. a char array[] ( or a pointer to text in mem. ) 
   Use strcmp to compare texts, if you need to.
3. no.